# Android: Choose Photo from Gallery

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-permissions

I am trying to access photo libraray in android device using this code:

```
txtSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener(v->{
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(i,GALLERY_CHANGE_PROFILE);
    });
```

but when it opens it just gives me a blank screen of the device folders with no photos like this although there are photos on the device.. is there any way to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `setType()` and instead pass a `Uri` in the `Intent` constructor, representing the collection that you want the user to pick from:

```
txtSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener(v->{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_CHANGE_PROFILE);
});
```

Or, keep the MIME type and switch to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`:

```
txtSelectPhoto.setOnClickListener(v->{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_CHANGE_PROFILE);
});
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is still show empty blank screen

Comment: @AlexAli: See the updated answer for another approach to the problem.